# How to insert in table from remote stored procedure without creating a distributed transaction?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, remote, distributed-transactions

How can I insert in a local table from a remote stored procedure without creating a distributed transaction? I want to run a stored procedure on a remote server and use the output as the source for an insert into a local table.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  You want to run a stored procedure on a remote server and use the output as the source for an insert into a local table, or what?

Comment: Yes, that's it...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For **SQL Server 2008 and up**, you can disable promotions for the linked server.  It's on the Advanced property tab, or you can script it like:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption 
    @server=N'YourLinkedServer', 
    @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', 
    @optvalue=N'false'
```

For **SQL Server 2005**, you can add an OLE DB linked server. That allows you to enter detailed options in the connection string.

Here's how to configure such a linked server.  Click `Server Objects`, then right click `Linked Servers` and choose `New Linked Server...`.  Configure the server as follows:

- Tab "General":

  - Linked server: *enter name of linked server*
  - *Check* Other data source
  - *Select provider* Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server
  - Product name: *Enter anything here, like ZzzZZzzzz*
  - *Enter provider string*
    `Data Source=<server or ip>,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=<database name>;Enlist=false;`
- Tab "Security":

  - *Choose* Be made using this security context
  - *Enter username and password*

The `Enlist=false` in the connection string should prevent distributed transactions.