# OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "[name]" was unable to begin a distributed transaction

Tags: linked-server, msdtc

I have a linked server setup from SQL Server Ent 2012 to PostgreSQL 9.3 and a stored procedure pulling 3 filtered tables from it and storing each in a temporary table.

There is a final query at the end of the Stored Procedure with many left joins, from local SQL Database and it includes these 3 temporary tables.
I have disabled "Enable promotion of distributed transactions for RPC". Every 1/6 or more attempts to use this Stored Procedure fails, with error on web server as:
`Unknown Error Detected
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "POSTGRESQL" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection`

No errors on the SQL Server though.

**Linked server definition:**

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'POSTGRESQL', @srvproduct=N'PostgreSQL', @provider=N'MSDASQL', @datasrc=N'PostgreSQL'
 EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'POSTGRESQL',@useself=N'False',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=N'xxxxxx',@rmtpassword='xxxxx'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'POSTGRESQL', @optname=N'collation compatible', @optvalue=N'false'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'POSTGRESQL', @optname=N'data access', @optvalue=N'true'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'POSTGRESQL', @optname=N'dist', @optvalue=N'false'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'POSTGRESQL', @optname=N'pub', @optvalue=N'false'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'POSTGRESQL', @optname=N'rpc', @optvalue=N'true'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'POSTGRESQL', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'true'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'POSTGRESQL', @optname=N'sub', @optvalue=N'false'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'POSTGRESQL', @optname=N'connect timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'POSTGRESQL', @optname=N'collation name', @optvalue=null
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'POSTGRESQL', @optname=N'lazy schema validation', @optvalue=N'false'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'POSTGRESQL', @optname=N'query timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'POSTGRESQL', @optname=N'use remote collation', @optvalue=N'true'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'POSTGRESQL', @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'false'
```

**Stored Procedure/Query**
(very simplified sorry)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Name]
@DateFrom DATETIME,
@DateTo DATETIME

AS

DECLARE @variableB int

SET @variableB= {some criteria} 

IF (@variableB < 1000)

BEGIN
-- Passthrough to PG for a filtered table, instead of entire table grabbed via open query
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temp_table1', 'U') IS NOT NULL
      DROP TABLE #temp_table1; 

    create table #temp_table1 (column1 int, column2 varchar(60))

    DECLARE @TSQL varchar(max)
    SET  @TSQL = 'select c1, c2 from OpenQuery([POSTGRESQL],''
            select c1, c2 from table1 t where 
            t.date>=''''' +CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),@DateFrom,102)+ '''''' + 't.date <=''''' +CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),@DateTo,102) + '''''' +'order by c1'')'

    insert into #temp_table1
    EXEC (@TSQL)

    create clustered index temp_index1 on #temp_table1 
    (column1 asc)
    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]

-- 2nd table passthrough to PG for a filtered table, instead of entire table grabbed via open query
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temp_table2', 'U') IS NOT NULL
      DROP TABLE temp_table2; 

    create table #temp_table2 (column1 int, column2 varchar(60), column3 int)

    SET  @TSQL = 'select a, b, c from OpenQuery([POSTGRESQL],''
            select a, b, c from table2 t where 
            t.date>=''''' +CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),@DateFrom,102)+ '''''' + 't.date <=''''' +CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),@DateTo,102) + '''''' +'order by a'')'

    insert into #temp_table2
    EXEC (@TSQL)

-- 3rd table passthrough to PG for a filtered table, instead of entire table grabbed via open query
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temp_table3', 'U') IS NOT NULL
      DROP TABLE temp_table3; 

    create table #temp_table3 (column1 int, column2 varchar(60))

    SET  @TSQL = 'select a1, a2, a3 from OpenQuery([POSTGRESQL],''
            select a1, a2, a3 
            from
            table3 t
            where 
            t.date>=''''' +CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),@DateFrom,102)+ '''''' + 't.date <=''''' +CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),@DateTo,102) + ''''''
{plus other filtering criteria} +'order by a1'')'

    insert into #temp_table2
    EXEC (@TSQL)

IF (@variableB < 1000)

BEGIN

select {many columns}
from {various local tables with left joins}
left join #temp_table1 on {conditions}
left join #temp_table2 on {conditions}
left join #temp_table3 on {conditions}

END
```

**Local DTC Properties**

[image]

- What I think is happening, is that the 3 openqueries into temp tables
  are getting distributed, and somehow that just doesn't work. I
  confess I don't understand [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177403(v=sql.105).aspx) very well - it's over my head. I
  also know that enabling "Enable promotion of distributed transactions
  for RPC" makes the fails happen more frequently.
- This again works 5/6 times and fails about 1/6 times. So I am not sure what is happening.
- This is a read only transaction on PostgreSQL - I am not sure why distributed transaction is getting invoked at all.

**Edit**
I see this question [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46541/how-to-insert-in-table-from-remote-stored-procedure-without-creating-a-distribut) and thinking I shouldn't be having this issue.

**Edit 2**
I may have a found a duplicate question [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46541/how-to-insert-in-table-from-remote-stored-procedure-without-creating-a-distribut).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapping the 3 temp table inserts in one transaction with ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED seems to have stopped promotion to a distributed transaction and solved my intermittent problem.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    DECLARE @TSQL varchar(max)
    SET  @TSQL = 'select c1, c2 from OpenQuery([POSTGRESQL],''
            select c1, c2 from table1 t where 
            t.date>=''''' +CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),@DateFrom,102)+ '''''' + 't.date <=''''' +CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),@DateTo,102) + '''''' +'order by c1'')'

    insert into #temp_table1
    EXEC (@TSQL)

.....etc

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

This was a duplicate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542605/net-how-to-disable-promotion-in-system-transactions) and ultimately gave me the solution. Perhaps, PostgreSQL ODBC does not support distributed transactions - and disabling them on Linked Server Properties is not enough when attempting to use temp tables or attempting to connect to a remote database 3 times -- due to ACID functionality..